# PYOMO: Indexing set of tuples

Tags: pyomo

I want to create an indexing set of tuples, i mean if i do:
`LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA[1]` I want to see `[(1,3),(1,2),(1,4)]`.

My code is:

```
m=ConcreteModel()
m.BARRAS = Set()
m.LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA = Set(dimen = 2)

m.LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA = Set(m.BARRAS, initialize=lambda m, i:
set(tuple(z) for z in m.LINEAS if (i == z[0])))
```

And the problem is:

> ValueError: The value=(1, 2) is a tuple for
>   set=LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA, which has dimen=1

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the Set m.LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA on a single line. Also, make sure that your lambda function is returning a **list** of tuples

```
m.LINEAS_DOWNSTREAM_BARRA = Set(m.BARRAS, dimen=2, initialize=your_lambda_fcn)
```